# multiprocessing on python on windows server

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to run my code on a Windows server with 56 cores, but it seems very slow. I am using a multiprocessing package on python 3.

Here is part of my code.

```
iterable = chunks
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes)
func = partial(functions.Calcualtion, df2, df1)
res = pool.map(func, iterable)
pool.close()
```

I have a DF that I divided it into chunks and two other dfs, df1, df2 that are the same for all calculations. I have defined functions that do the calculation. When it was running on my machine with 4 core it was faster than the server.

Any idea what is the possible problem?

Comment: It's really hard to know what's going on without any idea of what's in `df1`,`df2`, `chunks`, `functions.Calcualtion` (is the reason function misspelled like that?), etc. For example, maybe the problem is that `chunks` uses smaller chunks when there are more cores and the pickle/IPC cost starts to swamp the parallelism benefits. Or maybe `Calcualtion` uses shared data with a lot of locking. Or… there so many possibilities that it's pointless to mention them all.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's impossible to say. You don't give any details regarding the size of the dataset, if you use the same dataset in each environment, wether the windows server is busy serving other applications. Without context, no one can help you further

Comment: df1 and df2 are datafarme size of one them is 1 million rows the other is around 500000 rows. I read these dataframes and pass them to my calcualtion functions.

Comment: @abarnert: thanks for your reply, I wrote the Calculation function which is in functions class. I think you are right and the problem is locking. df1 and df2 is shared sources. I read them at the beginning of my code and pass them to calculation function. Do you think it is the partial tool?

Comment: If you think the problem might be locking, but you don’t show us a MCVE that reproduces the problem and includes the code that demonstrates your locking pattern, nobody can tell you whether or not you’re right. The best answer anyone can give is “Could be that, could be something else”.